# CORS and Spring MVC Services - How to setup cross origins hosts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors, same-origin-policy

### Preface

Consider these two webapps I have running locally:

- Frontend Webapp `localhost:8080`
- Service Webapp `localhost:2020`

### On my local development environment (working)

When I visit my **Frontend Webapp** I have JavaScript executed in the background. This JavaScript is firing XHR Requests to my **Service Webapp**. These calls are blocked by *SOP* (Same Origin Policy). Because my Frontend Webapp tries to call a service on another origin (which is port `2020` in this case).

To use *CORS* (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) I allowed my Frontend Webapp to access the Resource of my Service Webapp with Spring's `@CrossOrigin` [(Documentation)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) annotation.

```
  @CrossOrigin(Resources.Origins.FRONTEND) // http://localhost:8080
  @GetMapping(Resources.Services.APIs.History.STREAM)
  public SseEmitter subscribeToHistoryEvent() {
    // logic
  }
```

After I setup this I was successfully able to fire XHR Requests from my Frontend Webapp to my Service Webapp.

### On my virtual machine deployment environment (not working)

I then tried to deploy my applications to my virtual machine to test things from a remote perspective.

The webapps were now reachable by these URLs

- IP of my machine `192.50.3.100`
- Frontend Webapp `192.20.1.77:8080`
- Service Webapp `192.20.1.77:2020`

I was able to access my Frontend Webapp **but** it was not possible to fire XHR Requests to my Service Webapp again due *SOP*.

I think it is because I am now firing an XHR Request from my machine `192.50.3.100` to the Service Webapp which actually does only allow `http://localhost:8080` to access its resouces.

### My Conclusion

I misunderstood the way CORS should be used here I think. I should not fire XHR Request via JavaScript therefore from my BrowserClient to any cross origin service but I should rather call to my Frontend Webapp and let it do requests 
to another service living in another origin?

Please tell me what the right way of using CORS to step over SOP would be!

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access `http://localhost:8080` from your front end it accesses localhost of machine where JS is executed (where browser starts in fact).

Instead JS should call real IP of backend - 192.20.1.77:2020 rather than localhost:2020.

Comment: But that wouldn't be flexibel in terms of deployment locations? What if I redeploy in another environment? Then I had to rewrite javascript XHR request endpoints all the time or have some kind of dynamic config properties. Sure that's the only solution here?

Comment: The backend IP (or URL) must be configured. And definitely should not be localhost for prod. Localhost points to local machine. You can add e.g. properties file on front end app where the backend host is specified. E.g. in angular you can define in the main.bundle.js something like this var environment = {
    production: true,
    domain: 'http://192.20.1.77:2020',
};

Comment: Is there any problem using `window.location.host` ? Because this yields exactly the right url

Comment: Should be fine I guess. The difference is just port so the approach should work. Will fail if your backend host and front end host are different.